# Get finger position on touchpad

Tags: c#, c++, hardware-interface, touchpad

Is there any way to get the location that touch pad is touched?
also I need capture module that is able to return such 2D points array map that reports states of touchpad points (state means: **is point touched/not touched**) by request. No matter on what technology/language it is written

Comment: For clarity, I assume you're talking about a [Touchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchpad) pointing device, not the [HP TouchPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_TouchPad) tablet.

Comment: simple touch pad that every laptop has......Yes you are correct

Comment: This will probably vary depending on device, driver, and operating system.  Not all touch pads are multitouch. I would search google for something similar to "synaptic] multitouch gesture source code" to get  a basic idea of what your getting into.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this isn't what you want to hear, but there is no all-inclusive way to do what you want.

Individual makes and models have their own way of exposing it.  For example, [I've done some work with Synaptic touchpads](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic70834.html) (fairly common) which expose a COM interface on Windows.  That code won't work on any other touchpads.

You could find a few common ones and run different code based on which ones the system supports.

Comment: Yes, touchpads only deal with relative coordinates, unless specified otherwise by the driver. Since that would be a custom driver, your would have to create a custom solution for each supported device.

Answer (score 3):

If its a windows app, handle the WM_MOUSEMOVE message , the hiword and loword of the lparam is the x and y coordinates respectively , in reference to client area coordinates.