# Get finger position on a laptop touch pad (c#)

Tags: c#, vector, coordinates, touchpad

I'm looking to make use of the laptop touch pad, more specifically where on the pad the user's finger is currently touching, is there any way to get a coordinate/vector2 back of the location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get finger position on touchpad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377090/get-finger-position-on-touchpad)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no general way to access the real touchpad position since a touchpad normally perfectely emulates a normal mouse with all it's features. This means that normally you have relative mouse coordinates that you have to process in order to use it.

If you really want to implement this specific feature you will have to look at the specific SDKs from your touchpad manufacturer and even then it might not be possible due to the limitations of your device. It normally isn't even easy to get an absolute position with an (expensive) graphictablet and touchpads are even more stripped down.

My recommendation is to find another way of doing it. We know nothing about your project but I'm almost certain it would just be a rather useless gimmick because touchpads are almost 100% mousepads and not interactive touchscreen displays and therefore are not designed for this.

Comment: I would have given +1 if not for the last paragraph, pity :P

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Comment: I would just have left my personal assessment of the usefulness of the project out of the response. I'm not saying it can't be useless nor that it shouldn't be said, but we don't know what they have in mind :)

Comment: Yeah, I totally see your point... Nonetheless I felt like it had to be said that features like this often end up being hard to develop and very minor benefit from it. If you want we can edit it out so it's a plain objective response :)

Comment: Nah, a +1 is a very minor benefit :P Don't worry about it.