# Is it possible to get absolute touch position from touchpad?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, touch, driver

Is it possible to get absolute position from touchpad? 
It's really important for us in current project.

We want use it in Unity 3D. We can, for example, write some "driver-like-programm" to get position from low-lewel api (or something else), but we really don't know how to do it :(

Can anyone give us some advice or ideas how to implement this?

Comment: What happens if you use a mouse?

Comment: Absolute position of what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get finger position on touchpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377090/get-finger-position-on-touchpad)

Comment: Absolute position of touch.

Comment: We can't use mouse, because we have technical task :)

Answer (score 1):

So, we finded the solution.

We use the Wacom tablet with their multi-touch API to get TouchInfo.
It's important, that not all Wacom tablets supports that feature.

In this list only tablets with access to touch point data supports this:
http://www.wacomeng.com/touch/WacomFeelMulti-TouchFAQ.htm#_Toc331140757